# Как работает присвоение переменной со сменой типа

Tags: php

Кто объяснит почему так тот молодец)
Вопрос не в том, почему 0 при (int), а почему 0 == a34
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю как в `php`, но например в `c++`, если преобразовывать строку в число, то "парсер" будет парсить пока есть, что парсить. В общем у вас строка, которая начинается с `a` и на этом моменте "парсер" заканчивает работу и выдает 0. Опять токи в `c++` это так работает. Попробуйте написать `34a` должно получиться `b = 34`. И да тут код принято в виде тексте скидывать, а не картинкой :)

Comment: Павел, вопрос в не в 0 (то что PHP не сможет спарсить в данном случае, то это понятно )) вопрос в том, почему условие показывает, что 0 == a34.
Сейчас обновлю описание)

Comment: А ну так при `==` `$a` приводится к `int`, что равно 0. И получается `0 == 0 -> true` Я думаю нужно использовать `===` для сравнения с учетом типов данных.

Comment: Павел, действительно так) И при === будет false из-за сравнения типов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При таком (не строгом) сравнении `$a` приводится к сравниваемому типу - к числу. 'a34' в виде числа - это ноль (точнее в `"0"`). A `"0" == 0 -> true` (При `"0" === 0 -> false`)

Про преобразование типов написано в документации (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php)

> Примером автоматического преобразования типа является оператор
> умножения '*'. Если какой-либо из операндов является float, то все
> операнды интерпретируются как float, и результатом также будет float.
> В противном случае операнды будут интерпретироваться как int и
> результат также будет int.

```
<?php
    $foo = "1";  // $foo - это строка (ASCII-код 49)
    $foo *= 2;   // $foo теперь целое число (2)
    $foo = $foo * 1.3;  // $foo теперь число с плавающей точкой (2.6)
    $foo = 5 * "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo - это целое число (50)
    $foo = 5 * "10 Small Pigs";     // $foo - это целое число (50)
?>
```

Это же правило действует и при сравнении.

Comment: Супер) И да при === будет false из-за разных типов)

Comment: @it-blog.club Это я указал в ответе :)

Comment: Ну так правильно и указал) Вот только var_dump показывает, что $b это int. Ну сути не меняет.
$c = 0;
$d = "a34";
if ($c != $d) {
    echo "Не равно";
} else {
    echo "Равно"; //Попадём сюда
}

Comment: @it-blog.club не понимаю)) в указанном коде какая-то проблема?)) или просто подтверждение моих слов в ответе?))

Comment: Подтверждение слов конечно)

Comment: @it-blog.club если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку напротив ответа.